# Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

How do I change the background color and font in file explorer in Windows 10?  In Windows 7 and earlier it was easier.  You could set color and font for the various parts of the window itself.

Comment: one of the ways is in using an "Ease of Access" theme and settings.. which is far from what your asking, but something you could check out.

Answer (score -1):

You can hit Alt+shift+PrintSystem to switch to dark mode. (win10 afaik)
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/08/08/windows-10-tip-personalize-your-pc-by-enabling-the-dark-theme/

Comment: Please provide ALL relevant information within your answer itself.  You should quote and cite any statements that are not your own words.  Please don't use signatures like "bless you" they are just noise and will be removed by the community.